# dconf-gsettings-backend:armhf' contains empty filename

Tags: apt, update

**Question**

How to fix error code #2 when updating and upgrading on the raspbian OS?

**Background**

I get this error  when I'm  trying  to update and upgrade:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: files list file for package `dconf-gsettings-backend:armhf' contains empty file name
```

I have tried `apt-get -f` to no avail. Can you help me?

Here is complete error that I receive

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
files list file for package `dconf-gsettings-backend:armhf' contains empty filename
error code (2)
```

Comment: Welcome to SE. I recommend that you edit your answer to make it more readable. Also, for all parts that can be considered code, `put it in backquotes like this`. That will make it easier for us to see the actual errors and what you typed into the terminal.

Comment: Also, what did you type originally? `apt-get upgrade`? Where you trying to update the OS, firmware, or something else entirely?

Comment: Have you solved your problem? If so, please mark the answer that helped you, or if you solved it on your own, create a self-answer and mark it as such. We are trying to get the site Q:A ratio up and marking answers is what does that. If you resolved it and mark then people in the future will be able to profit from what you did *and* it helps move the site closer to graduation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. From what I can gather, you did not run as a super user. Instead of your normal commands, try typing these lines into the terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   sync
   reboot
   ```
2. If you are still having errors, I recommend seeing [this Question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/3338/6609). Also, try to [google your question](https://www.google.com/search?q=dpkg%3A+unrecoverable+fatal+error%2C+aborting%3A+files+list+file+for+package+%60dconf-gsettings-backend%3Aarmhf'+contains+empty+file+name&aq=f&oq=dpkg%3A+unrecoverable+fatal+error%2C+aborting%3A+files+list+file+for+package+%60dconf-gsettings-backend%3Aarmhf'+contains+empty+file+name&aqs=chrome.0.57j58j62.570j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&safe=active&sclient=psy-ab&q=dpkg+error+code+2+raspberry+pi&oq=dpkg+error+code+2+raspberry+pi&gs_l=serp.3..33i38.808245.809946.1.810224.13.13.0.0.0.0.358.1449.10j1j1j1.13.0...0.0...1c.1.8.psy-ab.EY3CdDPEmbo&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44697112,d.dmg&fp=c6c12a40d46f7a1&biw=1366&bih=667) and see this [question on the official forums.](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=31177&p=270332).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following script:

```
dpkg -c full-path-to-debfile | awk '{if ($6 == "./"){ print "/."; } \
else if (substr($6, length($6), 1) == "/") \
{print substr($6, 2, length($6) - 2); } \
else { print substr($6, 2, length($6) - 1);}}' \
> /var/lib/dpkg/info/packagename.list
```

Comment: Good script - bad explanation. @Łukasz Koniecki please explain your code with comments or something similar.